# why Gradient Descent doesn't work as expected with pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

so I'm starting with Pytorch and tried to start with an easy Linear Regression Example. Actually I made an easy Implementation of Linear Regression with Pytorch to calculate the equation 2*x+1 but the loss stay stuck at 120 and there is a Problem with Gradient Descent because it doesn't converge to a small loss value. I don't know why this is happening and it made me crazy because I don't see what's wrong. actually this example should be very easy to solve. this is the Code I'm using

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np

X = np.array([i for i in np.arange(1, 20)]).reshape(-1, 1)
X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
y = np.array([2*i+1 for i in np.arange(1, 20)]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

class LR(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, n_hidden1, n_out):
        super(LR, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(n_features, n_hidden1)

        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden1, n_out)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear(x))
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x

model = LR(1, 10, 1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

def train(epochs=100):
    for e in range(epochs):

        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f"epoch: {e} and loss= {loss}")
```

desired output is a small loss value and that the model train to give a good prediction later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your learning rate is too large. The model takes a few steps in the right direction, but it can't land on an actually good minimizer and henceforth zigzags around it. If you try `lr=0.001` instead,  your performance will be much better. This is why it's often useful to decay your learning rate over time when using first order optimizers.

Comment: it's wierd, I tried yesterday to minimize the learning rate but I didn't get a good result too, and now it works! can you tell me what do you specifically mean with first order optimizer ?

Comment: A first order optimizer like gradient descent only uses first order derivative information when taking a step. You compare this to a second order solver like newton's method, which calculates the hessian. The latter takes better steps but scales more poorly to high dimensional spaces. Consider this link, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201384/what-is-the-definition-of-a-first-order-method